# syntax terminology

Tags: syntax, terminology

Does anyone know the term for this form of command-line syntax notation?  For instance, when specifying command-line arguments:

```
key[,alignment][:format]
```

So that key is a required argument, and can be followed by a space and an alignment parameter, which can also be followed by a colon and a format.

It's not BNF.  Is there a name for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Command line argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_line_argument) from Wikipedia lists a couple of terms for the switch, options or flags syntax depending on what operating system and program you are using.